# Lambda function fails saying "mysql" command not found even after having node modules installed

Tags: mysql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am writing a lambda that would restore my Database schema into RDS. I have packed node modules in the zip that i have uploaded on aws lambda console. What is the issue over here? where i am going wrong?

This is my lambda function

```
var  MysqlTools= require('mysql-tools');
var endpoint = process.env.MYSQLDB_HOST;
var username = process.env.MYSQLDB_USER;
var database = process.env.MYSQLDB_DATABASE;
var password = process.env.MYSQLDB_PASSWORD;

exports.restore = (event,context)=>{
  var tool = new MysqlTools();
  tool.restoreDatabase({host: endpoint, user: username, password:password, sqlFilePath: 'epmoliteDump.sql', database:  database
  }, function (error, output, message) {
     if (error instanceof Error) {
        console.log(error);
     } else {
        console.log(output);
        console.log(message);
     }
  });
}
```

Cloud watch error log

> START RequestId: 303cd306-9ed3-11e7-874e-a5a3ce668160 Version: $LATEST
>   2017-09-21T13:45:54.531Z  303cd306-9ed3-11e7-874e-a5a3ce668160    { Error:
>   Command failed: mysql -h
>   me10uo7cwmpj.c8icuw7t60la.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u xxxxxx
>   -pxxxxxx eLite_DB
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:204:12)
> at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)   killed: false,   code: 127,
> ```
>
> signal: null,   cmd: 'mysql -h
>   me10uo7cwmpj.c8icuw7t60la.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u xxxxxx
>   -pxxxxxx eLite_DB

Comment: The `mysql-tools` library is just a wrapper around the `mysql` and `mysqldump` commands. It doesn't actually include those tools inside the NodeJS library. Those tools are a dependency that it expects you to have installed already. You would need to package those binaries in your Lambda deployment package. I'm not aware of anyone successfully installing and running the `mysql` or `mysqldump` utilities on AWS Lambda at this time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `mysql-tools` as it expects you to have the `mysql` utilities in your $PATH and there seems to be no way of configuring it in `mysql-tools`.

You can, however, include the `mysql` binary in your Lambda package provided that it is built for the matching version of Amazon Linux.

Assuming the binary's location is at `<root directory of lambda function>/bin/mysql`, you can change your code like this:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec
const endpoint = process.env.MYSQLDB_HOST;
const username = process.env.MYSQLDB_USER;
const database = process.env.MYSQLDB_DATABASE;
const password = process.env.MYSQLDB_PASSWORD;

exports.restore = (event, context) => exec(`${process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']}/bin/mysql -u ${username} -p${password} -h ${endpoint} ${database} < epmoliteDump.sql`, function (error, output, message) {
   if (error instanceof Error) {
      console.log(error);
   } else {
      console.log(output);
      console.log(message);
   }
});
```

Comment: It talks about dumping the backup, i am asking for restoring my existing SQL dump to RDS